# Scrapy response returns empty list

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I'm new to Scrapy and I'm trying to extract data from sport bets on sportsbooks.
I am currenty trying to extract data from the upcoming matches in the Premier League: https://sport.mrgreen.com/da-DK/filter/football/england/premier_league
(The site is in Danish)
First I have used the command "fetch" on the website, and I am able to return something back using the "response" command with both CSS and xpath from the body of the HTML code. However, when I want to extract data beyond a certain point in the HTML code ("div data-ui-view"), response just returns an empty list. (See picture)
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zf4D.png)
I have encircled the xpath in red. I return something when I run the following:

```
response.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div')
```

I have tried to use both CSS on the innermost class that I could find on the data I want to extract and the direct xpath as well. Still only an empty list.

```
response.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div')
```

(The above code returns "[]")

```
response.xpath('response.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[1]/a/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/button[1]/div/div[1]/div'))
```

(The above xpath is to a football club name)
Does anybody know what the problem might be? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't do `response.xpath(response.xpath())`, one `response` is enough; also, I always use `""` instead of `''`, and avoid using full xpath, that rarely works, instead try with `.//div` and see what returns, and for better results, use the search options that xpath has, like `response.xpath(".//div[contains(text(), 'Chelsea Wolves')]//text()`. Make sure your `response.url` matches with the url you want to scrapy.
Remember, a short and specific xpath is better than a large and ambiguos xpath.